# Adding multiple images to one canvas in Python

Tags: python, image

I want to load a number of images from harddrive and place them on a larger white background. And I want to do it in Python. I am wondering what is the best way of doing that. I am using a windows machine and I can use any library I want. Any pointer to a webpage or a sample code that can point me to a good direction would be appreciated.

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very popular image processing library for Python is [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/). The official [PIL tutorial](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/introduction.htm) might be useful, especially the section about "Cutting, Pasting and Merging Images".

Comment: Modern code should use [Pillow, the “friendly PIL fork”](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/), rather than the original PIL.

Answer (score 0):

`PIL` isn't enough. Try also with `PIL` the `aggdraw` library.

But `aggdraw` also isn't enough. It works poorly with transparency. I mean 0.5-1 gray pixel around opaque object over the transpparent area.